# Display next number from an array on click will showing 3 numbers all the time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

From this array  [21, 42, 54, 1, 87, 90, 56, 27, 89]

I am displaying first 3 numbers by default
next button want to shift one step and show as 42, 54, 1
on previous button click want to show one step behind  it like 21, 42, 54

but I am stuck
please sey by code what I am doing wrong, I am trying to increase the starting initial index number from which 3 numbers will be picked

```js
import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";
const App = () => {
  const list = [21, 42, 54, 1, 87, 90, 56, 27, 89];

  var start = 0;

  const handleClick = () => {
    start = start + 1;
  };

  var n = 3;

  var items = list.slice(start, n).map((i) => {
    return (
      <button style={{ margin: 10 }} type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
        {i}
      </button>
    );
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <div onClick={handleClick}>Click</div>
      <div>{items}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should store the `start` index in state.

```js
const [start, setStart] = useState(0);

const handleClick = () => {
  setStart(start + 1);
};
```

In addition, the second argument to `slice` should be the end index, not the number of elements to take. So the call to `Array#slice` should be like this:

```js
list.slice(start, start + n)
```

Working example:

```js
const App = () => {
  const list = [21, 42, 54, 1, 87, 90, 56, 27, 89];
  const [start, setStart] = React.useState(0);
  const handleClick = () => {
    setStart(start + 1);
  };
  const n = 3;
  const items = list.slice(start, start + n).map((item, idx) =>
      <button style={{ margin: 10 }} type="button" className="btn btn-primary" key={idx}>
        {item}
      </button>
  );
  return (
    <div>
      <div onClick={handleClick}>Click</div>
      <div>{items}</div>
    </div>
  );
};
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(<App/>);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use variables like that inside a react component because at every render the value of 0 will be set to your `start` variable.

Instead you should use [`states`](https://react.dev/learn/state-a-components-memory). See the working example:

```js
import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";
const App = () => {
  const list = [21, 42, 54, 1, 87, 90, 56, 27, 89];

  const [start, setStart] = useState(0);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setStart(start+1);
  };

  const n = 3;

  const items = list.slice(start, start + n).map((i) => {
    return (
      <button style={{ margin: 10 }} type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
        {i}
      </button>
    );
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <div onClick={handleClick}>Click</div>
      <div>{items}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Note that your slice code was also wrong since you are using a fixed `n`. Slice parameters are start and end index to slice, so you need to sum start and n.

Answer (score 0):

The key is to store the index [in state](https://react.dev/learn/managing-state) (`const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);`), and to use that state to guide how you're going to slice up the list `list.slice(index, index + 3)`. Remember that *how* a component is rendered depends on how it "reacts" to changes in state.

A few additional pointers:

1. If you're looking to have previous and next buttons you can implement those quite easily by using your `handleClick` function to cover both, and toggle the state depending on which button is clicked.
2. You can disable the buttons when `index` reaches 0, or index reaches the upper bounds of the list length.
3. Make sure that any component returned by a mapping process has a key (as shown below) or React will start yelling at you. Normally this key should correspond with an id in the data you're iterating over. In this case it's probably ok to use the `map` index parameter for this purpose (though it generally not recommended. Neither is using `uuid` FWIW).

```js
const { useState } = React;

const App = () => {
  
  const list = [21, 42, 54, 1, 87, 90, 56, 27, 89];

  const [ index, setIndex ] = useState(0);

  const handleClick = (e) => {
    const { value } = e.target;
    if (value === 'prev' && index >= 0) {
      setIndex(prev => prev -= 1);
    }
    if (value === 'next' && index < list.length - 3) {
      setIndex(prev => prev += 1);
    }
  };

  var items = list.slice(index, index + 3).map((n, i) => {
    return (
      <button
        key={i}
        style={{ margin: 10 }}
        type="button"
        className="btn btn-primary"
      >{n}
      </button>
    );
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <button
        className="direction"
        value="prev"
        type="button"
        disabled={index === 0}
        onClick={handleClick}
      >Prev
      </button>
      <button
        value="next"
        type="button"
        disabled={index === list.length - 3}
        onClick={handleClick}
      >Next
      </button>
      <div>{items}</div>
    </div>
  );

};

const node = document.getElementById('root');
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(node);
root.render(<App />);
```

```css
.direction:not(:last-of-type) { margin-right: 0.5rem; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```